# What if I extend a uclass without UClass() in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal, inheritance

What happens if I extend a uclass (or UObject) without the UClass() macro?

Will it still be a UClass() and managed by the garbage collector?

I'm just curious.

**Update**

I managed to extend ULineBatchComponent without `UCLASS` nor `GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()`, it compiled, did not complain, and I could instantiate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UCLASS` evaluates to a marker used by the Unreal Header tool to inject various bits of code, typedefs, attributes, and other bookkeeping information related to Unreal's reflection (and thus garbage collection) systems.

Anything that has `UCLASS` should also have `GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY` in the body of the class. Without both of those, your code *shouldn't* compile or link.

Failure to include `UCLASS` causes UHT to skip generation of the `YourFile.generated.h` header, which you should be including, and if you're not including that header you'll get compilation errors within the evaluation of `GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY`.

It may be possible to hack up the source file to get it through the compiler somehow (I stopped trying after a few basic attempts) but at that point you won't be able to instantiate or completely use the class because you won't have the related type info metadata Unreal's object system requires for things like `NewObject` to function.

**tl;dr**: bad things, don't do it.

Comment: Thx! I could extend ULineBatchComponent without UCLASS as I explained in my edit.

Comment: That's likely going to cause you trouble. You can instantiate it without Unreal's object system but you're going to be asking for bugs and memory leaks in the future.

Comment: Yes, I changed my code after your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to instantiate the class without it because the UCLASS() macro above the class declaration creates the global UClass instance (a ptr to which is returned when you do GetClass() on an instance of the UObject) describing that class' metadata, which is required for spawning it (either via the editor/dynamically or via NewObject<>)

That is, if UHT doesn't catch you using UPROPERTY/UFUNCTION inside the body of something that isnt declared as a UCLASS or USTRUCT beforehand, which will make it error on the preprocessing stage.

Comment: Thx! I could extend ULineBatchComponent without UCLASS as I explained in my edit.